# Converting Date string with offset to custom format ignoring the offset

Tags: java, jodatime

I have an input date string with an offset which I want to convert to a custom format. The problem is, when I do the conversion using Joda `DateTimeFormatter`, the resulting string is in my local timezone. How do I convert the string, but leave the timezone as it is?

This is what I have now:

```
public String getFormattedDate(String dateTimestamp) {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MMM d, yyyy h:m a");
        return fmt.print(new DateTime(dateTimestamp));
        //return new LocalDateTime(dateTimestamp).toString();
}
```

This is what I get:

```
input: 2017-03-20T00:00:00       | output: Mar 20, 2017 12:0 AM
input: 2017-03-23T15:12:24-04:00 | output: Mar 23, 2017 12:12 PM
```

When it is midnight, I do no get any offset (example 1). So this works fine. However, in the second example, I get an offset (timezone is EST). And my code converts it to my local time (PST). How do I avoid this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the date **retaining** the timezone, like this:

```
return fmt.print(ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(dateTimestamp));
```

The method `withOffsetParsed()` does the trick. With this code, I've got the following:

```
input: 2017-03-20T00:00:00       | output: Mar 20, 2017 12:0 AM
input: 2017-03-23T15:12:24-04:00 | output: Mar 23, 2017 3:12 PM
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not interested in timezones,  use LocalDateTime.

Comment: Thanks, but LocalDateTime throws an ```IllegalArgumentException``` when I pass a String with offset in it. I had tried that, but commented it out in my code above. Unless I can use it in another way?

Comment: If you don't care about the timezones then substring the input string to remove the timezones before parsing it into a LocalDateTime

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't want to split the input string because I would have to split it twice; once for "T"; and then another for the "-". Even though this would work, I'm accepting Hugo's answer.